# combination of "across" and "from", also question about "bee-lined for"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

Here is the text:

> Shahrbaraz, along with a smaller army, later managed to **slip through**
>   Heraclius' flanks and **bee-lined for Chalcedon**, **the Sasanian base
>   across the Bosphorus from Constantinople**.

Please help me understand bolded text. If I'm not wrong, "bee-lined for Chalcedon" means "*he went directly to* Chalcedon".

"to slip through" I think means "*to runaway from the inside of enemy's army*"

But the hardest part is "the Sasanian base across the Bosphorus from Constantinople". I have no idea about this.

Here is the source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahrbaraz#Siege_of_Constantinople

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of **bee-lined** is correct, it means "move directly toward," as a bee would fly from hive to flower and back.

**Slip through** means to travel through without disturbing.  It implies stealth in this case.  It does not mean to run away necessarily, or that Shahrbaraz's army was cowardly.  Instead here he slipped through the enemy's army because he knew that a fight would not end well and that he needed to reach a position beyond the army.  It's almost complimentary, even.

The final phrase is describing Chalcedon.  It was a Sasanian base and was located on the opposite side of the Bosphorus from Constantinople.

On a chess board, the white pieces are placed **across** the board **from** the black pieces.  They are on opposite sides of the board from one another.